# How to troubleshoot Paypal vault credit card charge failure

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to make a payment to a Paypal vault credit card using the Paypal Sandbox, but I can't figure it out. There appears to be no way to troubleshoot errors. It either works or it doesn't work, I haven't experienced it working.

I can pull lists of cards, I can retrieve a specific card, but I can't make a payment to any of them.

I'm using the PHP Paypal SDK. Here's what Paypal is seeing as my request.

```
{
    "body": {
        "intent": "sale",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "credit_card",
            "funding_instruments": [
                {
                    "credit_card_token": {
                        "credit_card_id": "CARD-6XP216179L970340WK6BNY5A",
                        "payer_id": "1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "transactions": [
            {
                "amount": {
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "total": "26.01"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "header": {
        "x-pp-silover": "name\\u003dSANDBOX3.API.1\\u0026silo_version\\u003d1880\\u0026app\\u003dplatformapiserv\\u0026TIME\\u003d1702332759\\u0026HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR\\u003d",
        "content-length": "233",
        "paypal-request-id": "323223593916288146862657311204",
        "x-slr-retry": "SLR-RETRY-EMPTY",
        "accept": "*/*",
        "client-auth": "No cert",
        "host": "api.sandbox.paypal.com",
        "user-agent": "PayPalSDK/PayPal-PHP-SDK 1.7.3 (platform-ver\\u003d5.6.23-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1; bit\\u003d64; os\\u003dLinux_4.4.0-21-generic; machine\\u003dx86_64; crypto-lib-ver\\u003d1.0.2h; curl\\u003d7.47.0)",
        "x-slr-nobounce": "true",
        "x-slr-orig-script_uri": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment",
        "x-pp-corrid": "793fa20aaec8b",
        "pp_remote_addr": "99.99.99.1",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxl4S0"
    },
    "additional_properties": {},
    "method": "POST"
}
```

I modified the IP to be something than what I am currently assigned. I don't know if it's a security issue to publish it, it's not secret.

The code I'm working with looks like this.

```
$apiContext = new \PayPal\Rest\ApiContext(
            new \PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential(
                $clientId,
                $secret
                )
            );

        $cardToken = new CreditCardToken();
        $cardToken->setCreditCardId($paymentMethod->getProcessorId());
        $cardToken->setPayerId("1");

        $fi = new FundingInstrument();
        $fi->setCreditCardToken($cardToken);

        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod("credit_card")
        ->setFundingInstruments(array($fi));
        $amount = new Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency("USD")
        ->setTotal("26.01");

        $transaction = new Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount);

        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent("sale")
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
        print_r($payment);

            $payment->create($apiContext);
            if ($payment->getState() == 'approved') {
                return TRUE;
            }
            return FALSE;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            print_r($ex);
        }
```

The $paymentMethod->getProcessorId() is a valid Credit Card Vault ID, which I can retrieve from Paypal's sandbox.

Here is Paypal's response.

```
{
    "status": 500,
    "duration_time": 135,
    "body": {
        "message": "An internal service error occurred.",
        "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
        "name": "INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR",
        "debug_id": "793fa20aaec8b"
    },
    "additional_properties": {},
    "header": {
        "Content-Length": "209",
        "Content-Language": "*",
        "X-SLR-RETRY": "500",
        "CORRELATION-ID": "793fa20aaec8b",
        "Date": "Fri, 15 Jul 2016 23:53:39 GMT",
        "Connection": "close",
        "Paypal-Debug-Id": "793fa20aaec8b",
        "PROXY_SERVER_INFO": "host\\u003dslcsbplatformapiserv3001.slc.paypal.com;threadId\\u003d569",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}
```

As I understand it, an internal error just means, something is not right, but it doesn't say what isn't right. It's annoying to work with, they give you nothing useful in the response to troubleshoot and there's apparently no logging to examine via Paypal SB dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an internal error, so it doesn't communicate what went wrong. It will be tough to receive a response here.

The best bet to get a response from PayPal would be to create an account at
https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/ and post the same question over there with the debug_id.  ( click Contact Support in the site footer ). They will tell what kind of error it is. I have a successful track record in getting help from them.

If the response from them take too long than the second best place to get help in case of Internal error is https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK also post debug_id over there.

Comment: I did that and they did get back with me. I needed to use these card numbers to test with. VISA : 4716 3248 7603 0777 
Mastercard : 5453 9874 8085 6045

Comment: There are few credit cards that are over used in PayPal Sandbox, and are causing weird behaviors. Think of a credit card with half a million billing address. These issues are covered well in live, but in sandbox, it causes these issues. The best idea would be to use a unique credit card. You can use step 4 of https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1413&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en to help you create one, or http://www.getcreditcardnumbers.com/ for a huge bulk.